# Spiroid Winglets Cad models details requirement

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, winglets, model-aircraft, cfd

Can anyone know where I can find spiroid winglets cad models? As iam conducting an experimentation on spiroid winglets.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE. Unfortunately, resource location questions like this are off-topic here.